# Make nginx switch the server on 500 internal server error

Tags: nginx, switch

I wanted to use nginx to switch between servers when an 500 error code is send as reply from an upstream server to a request from the client. How can this be done?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a 500 status response as a basis for fencing a node unless this is *purely* a static content server. If you've got application code running, then it should be using something else (500 is far too generic) to indicate the node should be fenced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *proxy_next_upstream* in location.

```
proxy_next_upstream http_500;
```

valid choices include: error|timeout|invalid_header|http_500|http_502|http_503|http_404 etc. Can be combined using space as a delimiter:

```
proxy_next_upstream timeout error http_500 <etc>;
```